# how to use getRunningAppProcesses() in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

i have the following piece of code :

```
package com.example.task;

import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainTask extends Activity {

private Button BprocessesShow;
private TextView processesShow;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_task);

    ActivityManager manager =       (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
     final List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();


    BprocessesShow=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.BshowProcesses);
    processesShow=(TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.showProcesses);     


    BprocessesShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            processesShow.setText((CharSequence) runningProcesses);
        }
    });

}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_task, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

well all i want to do is, when the user presses the button i made i want to  show him/her all the running processes that has on his phone ...When i'm running this application on my cellphone the app crashes and all i get is a message Unfortunately Task(that's my name's app) has stopped...Any help would be very useful!!

Comment: A LogCat would be useful for us to help you.

Comment: Also, I don't think you can just cast a List into a CharSequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
processesShow.setText((CharSequence) runningProcesses);
```

you are casting a List into a CharSequence.  Try something along these lines:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo process: runningProcesses) {
    b.append(processs.processName);
    b.append("\n");
}
processesShow.setText(b.toString());
```

Comment: Does this work well on Android 6 ? For me, it shows only a single item in the returned list (the one of the current app).

Comment: No it won't. Android stopped supporting this functionality.