# Android 6.0: Get package name of current activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-package-managers

How to get current activity package name? as `getRunningAppProcesses()` not working in Android 6.0.

Below is my code:

```
grdPhoto.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        //get package name of current running application.
        ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        packageName = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses().get(1).processName;

        Log.e("Package name:===========      ", "Package name     " + packageName);

    }
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792653/how-to-use-getrunningappprocesses-in-android

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066231/how-to-gettopactivity-name-or-get-current-running-application-package-name-in-lo

Comment: Thanks for reply but it is not working on android 6.0 to get current running application package name.

Answer (score 4):

Get the package name:

```
getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
```

Refer to this as well: [Get package name.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589797/how-to-get-package-name-from-anywhere)

Answer (score 2):

This code is unnecessary:

```
//get package name of current running application.
ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
packageName = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses().get(1).processName;
```

Try this:

```
grdPhoto.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //get package name of current running application.
        Log.e("Package name:===========      ", "Package name     " + getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
           }
});
```

If that doesn't work, you know there's a problem with your ontemclicklistener, so try this in your oncreate method or as a log to show proof that `getApplicationContext().getPackageName()`  will get the correct application package name.

```
Toast.makeText(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```